# Onsen UI: Automatic scroll with ons-list

Tags: onsen-ui

i want to program a chat in WhatsApp style.
The latest news will be shown below, and for new messages to be automatically scrolled down.
Can anyone help me how I can realize the automatic scrolling with ons-list?

```
<ons-template id="chat.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="ChatController">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
            <div class="center">Chat</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <ons-list style="margin-top: 10px" scroll-glue>
            <ons-list-item class="item" ng-repeat="msg in messages">
                <header>
                    <span class="item-title">{{msg.user}}</span>
                </header>
                <p class="item-desc">{{msg.msg}}</p>
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used WhatsApp, but this might help. In an `ons-page`, you can use `.page__content`'s `scrollTop` property for auto scroll. Like below. It uses jQuery for animation.

```js
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('ChatController', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.messages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
  $timeout(function(){
    $('.page__content').animate({scrollTop: $('.ons-list-inner').height()}, 2000)
    .animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.8/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.8/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.8/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.8/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-navigator page="chat.html"></ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="chat.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="ChatController">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
            <div class="center">Chat</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <ons-list style="margin-top: 10px" scroll-glue>
            <ons-list-item class="item" ng-repeat="msg in messages">
                <header>
                    <span class="item-title">{{msg.user}}</span>
                </header>
                <p class="item-desc">{{msg.msg}}</p>
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but with the code
$('.page__content').animate({scrollTop: 1000}, 2000);
it scrolls every time to position 1000px.

With $(document).height() it keep getting 646px. It is the initial height of ons-page. When the DOM is changing (new ons-list-item add), its the same height. But then I will scroll down to the end of the page.

How can i get the right height of page?

Comment: I edited my code. `<ons-list>` has height of sum of all `<list-item>`s, so this will work. Pay attention that I wrapped my animation code with `$timeout`. This is because you have to wait until the dom is finished loading before calculate the height.

Comment: @quersumme please accept this answer if you consider it valid.